# Angular, Interpolation properties with names containing dot

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an HTTP GET request with a response containing properties names with dot '.'
Exemple: 'first.name' and 'last.name'

So I created a class model like

```
export class GetUser{
   'first.name': string;
   'last.name': string;
   city: string;
}
```

and my request :

```
  private getUser(user?: User): Observable<GetUser[]> {
    return this.http.get<GetUser[]>(`${.API_URL}/user`);
  }
```

The request work and I have my object, but when I want use this object in my template HTML Angular
I can't use the interpolation like

```
{{ user.first.name }}
```

It's doesnt work.

It's possible to make a binding with a property with a dot ?

So, I thought make a mapper or an decorator for convert the property name 'first.name' to 'firstName'

How I can make a mapper response ?

Thank

Comment: Try `{{user['first.name']}}`

Comment: @David, yes, perfect, thank David

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `{{ user['first.name'] }}` in the template, but most likely it's better to parse it, for readability purposes. Which could be done like this:

```
export class GetUser {
  'first.name': string;
  'last.name': string;
  city: string;
}

export class User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  city: string;
}

private getUser(user?: User): Observable<User []> {
  return this.http.get<GetUser[]>(`${.API_URL}/user`).pipe(
    map((user) => parseDotProperties(user))
  );
}

export function parseDotProperties<
  T extends object = {},
  U extends object = {}
>(obj: U): T {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((parsed, key: string) => {
    const propertyName = key.split('.').map((part, i) =>
     i ? part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1) : part
    ).join('') as keyof T;

    parsed[propertyName] = obj[key as keyof U] as any;

    return parsed;
  }, {} as T)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=7#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmAXAqheAnaBvAUNfA5AGYCW6EiAdAHZgC28BAXNBeidQOYDceh4FGvUYs2HHn2jASiAJ4B+UYnZdeAXxw5QkGKgzY+pcogBywxa2Xje+AafNKVE-NLkWxqnBpxEArtWBEEgB7amhOJD10AApfNHQWBBR4gEoWKIN8dCRfdDCABzByeAARYMQABXRg-Iwg+AhY1K9NPwCg0OhC4rLK6tr0eogAHj4AFWh4AA9EeGoAExhggCMAK3hA6ABebDUAGj5kSZm5xegV9c2drA0APmiL9LToCdwsnLzoAHk1jaoAa3gskaFxSlGy818wHg0Wi3TQ8z20EBskc4hS21umXwUlCFC6-TqsjMDG2yKBlAg+RAMmiBEoBDBdDA+Vh3UQSJIGK2t0k+BI0HkXSKVGAAAsigBBRDRAAMYMQwWQ+QGAGFIDCMQBqYWDSk06HRACMGJY7L5YNWwQ4dMZ0Eg5NkwSIL14fPh8HmAG18oTBsThABdMkXL0o+0wFHO6DIYMOsDUWRunHQbKIXIFIoImzQfa7CMvFItLR4xDQOL6a586DEMiCWgMZg1owUAgHHEEOxCRssAgNxjtlwyVE11wBxsHbzAPHBEDwSggYKcaIRZIYJoYFIpbhAA)